# Question regarding Hatcher Exercise 0.24

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

The excercise wants us to show that for CW complexes $X$ and $Y$ with $0$-cells $x_0$ and $y_0$, we have a homeomorphism between the two spaces
$$X*Y/(X*\{y_0\} \cup \{x_0\}*Y) \cong S(X \wedge Y)/S(\{x_0\} \wedge \{y_0\}).$$
I was reading the proof in this post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69289/cw-complexes-exercise-from-hatcher) as well as the [solution found here](https://math.solverer.com/library/allen_hatcher/algebraic_topology/exercise_0-24). Both began with looking at the subspace $$I \times (X \times \{y_0\} \cup \{x_0\} \times Y) = (I \times X \times \{y_0\}) \cup (I \times \{x_0\} \times Y) \subset I \times X \times Y$$
and deduced that it gets identified to the subspace $X*\{y_0\} \cup \{x_0\}*Y$ in $X*Y$ which is completely fine. Then both posts claims that we automatically get a homeomorphism
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}\frac{I \times X \times Y}{I \times (X \times \{y_0\} \cup \{x_0\} \times Y)} \cong \frac{X*Y}{X*\{y_0\} \cup \{x_0\}*Y}.\end{equation}
My question is, why do we have this? I am assuming the quotients just mean the subspaces $I \times (X \times \{y_0\} \cup \{x_0\} \times Y)$ and $X*\{y_0\} \cup \{x_0\}*Y$ are being collapsed to a point in the respective spaces.

However, what about points of the form $(0,x_1,y_1) \in I \times X \times Y$ for $x_1 \neq x_0$ and $y_1 \neq y_1$? When constructing $X*Y$, such point is identified with $(0, x_1, y_0)$ since $\{0\} \times X \times Y$ gets collapsed to $\{0\} \times X$ in $X*Y$. However, in the above homemorphism, since such a point $(0,x_1,y_1) \notin I \times (X \times \{y_0\} \cup \{x_0\} \times Y)$ i.e. it is not identified with anything on the LHS after taking the quotient whereas, it is identified in the RHS when constructing $X*Y$. So how can the two quotient spaces be homeomorphic?

Comment: Solution manual? Something some student wrote up and made it sound like Hatcher deemed it correct and valid?

Comment: @TedShifrin I have corrected the link description. So are you claiming that their 'proofs' aren't correct?

Comment: This is the first time I've seen this for that book, and I haven't read the solution. I do know that I've come across things on the web claiming to be solutions manuals for textbooks *I* have written, and they are totally unauthorized and, from the few items I've checked, far from what would be in a true solutions manual. These are some individuals or companies trying to bilk the public.

Comment: Indeed, that "author" has posted ["solutions" to various problems in various textbooks](https://math.solverer.com/users/awasthi). Google research shows that he earned a doctorate in mathematics, with a concentration in cryptography. But to post his smattering of textbook solutions as solutions manuals is pompous and, IMHO, not to be trusted.

Comment: Anyhow, back to your question. It seems that the basic quotient construction by which we get from $I\times X\times Y$ to $X*Y$ has been lost. It is definitely *not*  identifying the quotienting subspace to a point, as you suggest.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for this. So are you saying that the original identification done when constructing $X*Y$ from $I \times X \times Y$ should still be done when forming the quotient space $\frac{I \times X \times Y}{\text{that subspace}}$?

Comment: Yes, I certainly would say so. Try writing the original equivalence relation as $\sim$ and keep track of it explicitly.